# github how to delete old ssh key on my mac?

Tags: git, macos, github, version-control, ssh-keys

Hi I recently purchased a used mac for development, however when I try to push code from my mac to my github repository. I will be getting this error:**Permission to myself/testuser.git denied to oldmacowner for example.**

I am wondering how to go about this. I think I need to delete the old ssh key that belongs to the oldmacuser and set up a new ssh key from github. Anyone have an idea of how to go about it? Thanks.

Comment: Why is there still any data from the previous owner on? Best to reformat and reinstall the whole machine.

Answer (score 9):

What i had to do is -

Open terminal

```
cd ~/.ssh
open .
```

Then folder opened in finder then i removed id_***.pub (SSH key files). Then followed following instructions -

- In Finder, search for the Keychain Access app.
- In Keychain Access, search for github.com.
- GitHub Password Entry in KeychainFind the "internet password" entry for github.com.
- Edit or delete the entry accordingly.

  https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

Usually in `OS X` ssh keys are stored in:

```
~/.ssh
```

If you need to remove one of them:

```
rm keyname_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should change the global configuration of git.
- `$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"`
- `$ git config --global user.email youremail@example.com`
- Add the ssh key of into your github account.
- Copy and paste the output of this `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub`

P.S : I am assuming the public keys are stored into `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: If you do that without first generating a new key, you have given the previous owner of the laptop full access to all your Github repositories.

Comment: @thilo : I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a few things:

1. Check for SSH keys in the Keychain Access app and remove them. These keys would be under "Local Items" if the user ever ran `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_private_key`
2. Ensure that your primary email in [GitHub settings](https://github.com/settings/emails) matches with you local git configuration - the one you used with `git config --global user.email 'your.email@domain.com'`

I suggest renaming your local GitHub SSH key before 2.