# Trying to remove old SSH key but couldn't find it?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm facing the similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691375/github-how-to-delete-old-ssh-key-on-my-mac) where I couldn't push the code to repo. So trying to access `~/.ssh` but it's not found?

I've also made sure that I've configured both user and email on global level as below

```
git config --global user.name "New Name"
git config --global user.email "New Email"
```

But when I try to push my code, it's still hitting permission denied? Where is this hidden ssh key?

Below is the exception that I'm getting

> remote: Permission to newUser/testing.git denied to oldUserName.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/newUser/testing.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

**UPDATES:**

When I run the command `git remote -v`:

```
origin  https://github.com/newUser/testing.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/newUser/testing.git (push)
```

Comment: you can always delete ssh key at remote and then create a new one locally and paste it to remote.

Comment: @22kar: It's a new repo and brand new github account. I don't think there is any ssh key at remote?

Comment: could you paste the error that you see when you do git push

Comment: @22kar: I've included the exception above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to access git over https, which has nothing to do with ssh.

Answer (score 2):

You are using *git* over *https*, which has nothing to do with SSH.

Below are the steps to get the access to your repo over SSH:

1. Switch your repo from HTTPS to SSH:

   ```
   git remote remove origin
   git remote add origin git@github.com:newUser/testing.git
   ```
2. Generate new SSH key (unless you have one):

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "newUser@example.com"
   ```

   More detailed info is [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#generating-a-new-ssh-key).
3. Add new SSH key to your Github account:

   Follow [these steps](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).
4. Add following into `~/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host github.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```
5. Enjoy

Comment: For steps number 4 is it copy bluntly without changing any detail?

Comment: Yes. Just copy this block into `~/.ssh/config`, and check that key file name is correct (in case you have multiple keys).

Comment: Actually the error I'm getting is "Permission to newUser/testing.git denied to oldUserName". Whether I use git over https or SSH, there should be some way somehow git recognize my pc as the old user right?

Comment: And `git config --global user.name "New Name"` is not sufficient to change my identity of PC to newUser?

Comment: Have you done all the steps as I specified? Also, are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: `user.name`/`user.email` has nothing to do with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because you are trying to push your changes to a repository you don't have access to. Check out the output of-

```
git remote -v
```

This should show you origin which points to your remote github account. If your URL is incorrect, you can set to the right location by-

```
git remote set-url origin <urltoyourremote>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you again look at my updated details? I've run your command and able to see the remote being set.

Comment: Is it a private repo? I just tried to hit it with curl. Got a 404. If its public and a brand new repo, make sure you've finished the email verification process.